# error in all false (r0) object 'r_all0' not found

Tags: r, rstudio, cross-validation, glmnet

I am getting the below error while trying `cv.glmnet` from `glmnet` package in R.

```
Error in all false (r0) object 'r_all0' not found
```

Code below

```
{wrap.glmnet.mdl.cv <- cv.glmnet(red.trn.x, red.trn.y, family="binomial")}
```

I am not able to figure out which "r_all0" object is referred here. Also, there is no such variable in the `red.trn.x` matrix.

Comment: Please add sample data and enough code to make your problem [reproducible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Ideally we should be able to copy and paste the code from this question into R to get the same error as you. That will make it much easier to help you.

Comment: May need to grep through the code base for `r_all0`.

Comment: @BondedDust I tried the source code for cv.glmnet but could not find 'r_all0'

Comment: `r0` appears several times in the source but I admit I am still unable to answer the question.

Comment: What does `traceback()` show after the error?